# Spring cloud config server APPLICATION FAILED TO START when use Open JDK 11

Tags: spring-cloud-config

I am trying to use Spring cloud config server in my project. I am using openJdk 11.

I am not using git URI. I have used  few yml files which are located under resources config folder

I am getting below error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Invalid config server configuration.

Action:

If you are using the git profile, you need to set a Git URI in your configuration.  If you are using a native profile and have spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap=true, you need to use a composite configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Cloud Config Server feature you need to provide proper configuration for service to start. Default profile is `git`, you need to provide URI to the repository which contains configuration.

From reference doc:

> Spring Cloud Config Server pulls configuration for remote clients from a git repository (which must be provided), as shown in the following example:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/config-repo
```

See more at: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/2.0.2.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_quick_start

Answer (score 0):

**Try below application.property file of config server**

```
server.port = 8888

spring.cloud.config.server.native.search-locations=file:///C:/configprop/

spring.profiles.active=native
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow ! You should take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) on StackOverflow, explaining how to properly ask a question. The community is here to help you, but you definitely need to provide more details to help us answer your question :) (such as code samples, giving more context of what you are trying to achieve, etc)

Answer (score 0):

you need configure your applicarion.yml as below:

```
server:
  port: 8888
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        composite:
          - type: native
            search-locations: classpath:/shared
  security:
    user:
      password: 'your-any-password'
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

and your configs of other apps lied in resources/shared folder